# C# Outlook Plugin- Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, outlook

I am working on a C# plugin for Outlook that will act when an item is added to the Deleted Items folder.  Roughly speaking, the code looks like this.  I see the log vent when the method is added, but when I delete an item, the other log event doesn't get fired.  What am I missing?

```
public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
{
    try
    {
    Outlook._Application olApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    Outlook._NameSpace olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder deletedFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
    deletedFolder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(DeletedItems_ItemAdd);
    log("addDeletedItemEventHandler method added", LogLevel.Debug);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    log("Exception in addDeletedItemEventHandler: " + e.Message, LogLevel.Error);
    }
}


private void DeletedItems_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
    log("DeletedItems_ItemAdd - Fired", LogLevel.Debug);
}
```

Dmitry's solution was correct.  For anyone else who's looking to solve this problem:
I defined the following at the class level: 
    Outlook.Items oiDeletedFolderItems;

And in the OnConnection method, I added/ changed:
    oiDeletedFolderItems = deletedFolder.Items;
    oiDeletedFolderItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(DeletedItems_ItemAdd);

Comment: Have you debugged your code to determine which line is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COM object that fires the events (Items) must be alive to fire events. In your case, the compiler creates a temporary variable to hold the result of the call to deletedFolder.Items; as soon as that variable is garbage collected, the events stop firing.

Store Items object in a class variable and hook events on that object.